# Using for loop to print out numbers between 1-100 multiples of 3 are red and underlined and multiples of 5 are blue and italicized

Tags: html, css, asp.net, numbers

I need help in writing a for loop..This is the first time i am writing a for loop and have no idea how to do it.. can some one please help me?

I want to do something like in the pic.. 
- multiples of 3 are red and underlined 
- multiples of 5 are blue and underlined
- number multiplied with both 3 and 5 is italicized underlined and purple
- numbers which do not fall under any categories are black and bold

[Numbers from 1-100 with multiples of 3 being red and underlined and 5 blue and underlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Oxz.png)

Comment: Search google for `fizzbuzz`.

Comment: Is it me or the picture's link is broken? and why we have both `php` and `asp.net` tags

Comment: @u_mulder thank u for the reply. i already tried it but i don't know how to change it to colors..

Comment: @sinaza am sorry.. i tried to post pic.. but it is saying i need 10 reputations to be able to post a pic..

Comment: Regarding fizzbuzz, you might also want to read this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. One way is this:

```
  <?php  
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; ++$i) {

     $mod3 = $i % 3;
     $mod5 = $i % 5;
     $str = '';
     if (!$mod3) {
       $str = '<p style="color: red;"><u>$i</u></p>';
     }
     if (!$mod5) {
       $str .= '<p style="color: blue;"><u>$i</u></p>';
     }
     if ($mod3 && $mod5) {
       $str .= '<p style="color: purple;"><em>$i</em></p>';
     }
     echo $str, "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. its working.. :D